# X2JSON conversion results in null object

Tags: json, xml, web-services

I am trying to use a [geonames](http://www.geonames.org/) web service to get an xml document and then convert the document to a json object.

I am using [X2JSON](https://github.com/abdmob/x2js)

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#city-select").append('<option selected disabled>City</option>');
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://api.geonames.org/countryInfo?username=elion"
    }).then(function(allCountries) {
        // Create x2js instance with default config
        var x2js = new X2JS();
        var jsonObj = x2js.xml_str2json( allCountries.children[0].children );
    });
});
```

Here is the [xml document](http://api.geonames.org/countryInfo?username=elion)

`jsonObj` ends up being null and there are no errors in the console.

Why is `jsonObj` null?